# impala string function to extract text after a given separator

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, cloudera, impala

Say I have a string of variable length such as:

```
'633000000HIQWA4:005160000UT334'
'00YYSKSG004:00YJDJJDA3443'
'300SGDK112WA4:00KFJJD900'
```

which impala string function to use to extract text after `:`
for e.g.:

```
'005160000UT334'
'00YJDJJDA3443'
'00KFJJD900'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split_part(string source, string delimiter, bigint n)` function. The value of `n` would be as the fields are numbered starting from 1.

```
select split_part('633000000HIQWA4:005160000UT334',':',2);

+----------------------------------------------------+
| split_part('633000000HIQWA4:005160000UT334',':',2) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 005160000UT334                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works

```
select
 CONCAT( split_part(cast((1347/100+11)%12+1 as varchar(2)),'.',1), ':',substring(cast((1347%100+100) as char(3)),2,2),
 ' ',CASE (1347 / 1200) WHEN 0 THEN 'am' ELSE 'pm' END)**
```

Output :1:47pm